# tags like <sampletag> are missing from the response after adding new utterances to the existing qna pair in qnamaker

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

In Qnamaker if i try to modify the utterance list of existing qna maker and if the response have tags like  then those tags are missed from the response after retraining the model. Any ideas on why is this happening or how do we need to overcome this?

Thanks in advance

Here is the sample qna pair which has a tag.We are using this tag in the backend. 
[image]

After adding new utterances, the tag is missing from the response.
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of an example question/answer pair with the what you have in the answer vs what's in the 'test' pane?

Comment: Hi @JJ_Wailes , updated the screenshots in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QnAMaker stores question/answer pairs in markdown, and html-like tags are automatically stripped out.

You can either use attempt to force the issue using special entity code like `&lt;` and `&gt;` (probably not going to get the results you're expecting), or I would change up how you're handling your QnA in your bot  using something like dispatch.

As a rough example, say you've got users that are using your QnA to say 'purpose 1' and 'purpose 2' (what you'd be tagging the answers with). You can split 'purpose 1' and 'purpose 2' into two separate KBs, and in your bot, you add in dispatch which looks for the "purpose" (intent), and shuffles your user off to the appropriate KB. At the same time, you can add in methods to handle what you need to outside QnA. That way it's your bot's logic that's handling whatever it is you need to handle with those tags, not QnA.